# sqlite - conditional replace and insert

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

working environment: using sqlite for android os. Doing bulk insert.

consider the following schema or [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e5ca7/1):

```
CREATE TABLE employee_data
    (
     id varchar(20) primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     dept varchar(20), 
     updation_date varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO employee_data
(id, name, dept, updation_date)
VALUES
("1", "john", "tech", "2017-04-30");

INSERT INTO employee_data
(id, name, dept, updation_date)
VALUES
("2", "john2", "tech", "2017-05-01");
```

While adding an entry to employee_data table, following conditions must be met:

1. if given entry does not already exists (compared on the basis of id), then add it.
2. if the id already exists; then check the 'updation_date' column - 
   if updation_date of entry to be added is later compare to the one that already exists - then update the row.
   else do nothing.

Example:
I)
need to insert `("1", "john", "management", "2017-05-01")` 
as there is already an entry with id = 1, check for updation_date;
now since "2017-05-01" is more recent data - update the row.
so ouput -  `("1", "john", "management", "2017-05-01")`

II) 
need to insert `("3", "steve", "management", "2017-06-01")` 
as no entry with id= 3 in employee_data, directly add this one
output: `("3", "steve", "management", "2017-06-01")  is added.`

III)

```
("2", "john2", "tech", "2017-04-01");
```

as `id=2` row exists with more recent updation_date `("2017-05-01")`
do nothing.

I have tried to search but could not find solution. I can't figure out how can I use insert into select statement. Or whether I can use select from dual.
I remember using merge in oracle for similar use case.

Note:
`updation_date` column can be changed to timestamp format or date format for ease in comparing it.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean Insert or Update?

Comment: I think you need to use a trigger. https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: no not insert or update.

Comment: why triggers? can we not use simple query?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database; you are supposed to implement complex logic in your application:

```java
void conditionalReplaceAndInsert(ContentValues cv)
{
    String oldDate = DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
                "SELECT updation_date FROM employee_data WHERE id = ?",
                new String[]{ cv.getAsString("id") });
    if (oldDate.equals(""))
        db.insertOrThrow("employee_data", null, cv);
    else if (oldDate.compareTo(cv.getAsString("updation_date")) < 0)
        db.update("employee_data", cv, "id = ?",
                   new String[]{ cv.getAsString("id") });
    else
        ; // do nothing
}
```